# .NET Core IIS websites stopped working HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: .net-framework, core

After I updated vs2017 to the latest version this morning and uninstalled vs2019 Enterprise Preview (v16.0) and installed vs2019 Enterprise (v16.1), and installed latest Windows updates all .NET Core 2.0.0 website no longer starting.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Complaining  about web.onfig file:

Specifically regarding this element:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Line number: 10
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore' cannot be read because it is missing section definition

Comment: web.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 411a84e3-bdaa-45d8-89a2-b47670e591eb-->

Comment: Problematic element:
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />

Comment: Please [edit] and add your comments to the question formatted properly as code.

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled all .NET Frameworks and installed - it fixed the problem:

Runtime 2.2.4: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle

Comment: I've been stuck with this for the past 3 hours. Your 0 upvote comment from a year ago solved it. Uninstalled all .Net Core runtimes/sdks/whatever on the server, and only installed the ASP.NET Core 3.1 Windows Hosting Bundle. Worked straight away. Thanks.

Comment: Mine happened to be simply reinstalling .net5 hosting bundle, but that's all I neded to do. Thanks!